# I need to have a running count of submitted zip codes for multiple regions in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, counting, tally

I need to have a tally of zip codes per city.  EX: San Francisco  (4)
and as more zipcodes are submitted to add to that tally.  I have tried COUNTIF and COUNTIFS but I am checking against 50+ criterion as each greater Metropolitan area has many different zip codes.  I have a list of all the zip codes needed for the tally.

[image]

I need a to have a running count in B2 if any numbers in column D are already in column A or are appended to column A in the future.  And the same for Column E.

Comment: please share a sample sheet.

Comment: Whenever possible, try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way

Comment: Unfortunately I can't due to the confidential nature.  I have a list of 250+ zip codes and a form that is updated as data comes in and one column is zip codes.  I need a tally of how many of the zip codes on the list show up in the form submissions.  So far I am manually writing COUNTIF(Range, Criterion)+Countif(Range, Criterion) and that is working but taking forever.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to assist you without knowing at least the formatting of your sheet. Where do the zip codes reside? What is the range? What is an example of the criterion? I could say extract every city/zip code from a list then tag on the count for each of them but I don't know if this even fulfills your need.

Comment: The community is so helpful, but, as mentioned by Kevin, it's nearly impossible to get this figured out without a practical example, a file with dummy data, maybe... I've learned overtime that building an example of the situation is worth the effort...

Comment: I have added a screenshot of some dummy data.  Hope that helps.  Thanks!

Comment: Well that could be as simple as `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D1:D<>"",COUNTIFS(A1:A,D1:D),""))` in an adjacent cell but I think you're looking for something more robust?

Comment: Essentially that's what I am looking for!  However I wrote the formula in column E and the numbers were tallied down the column next to the corresponding zip code.  I would like to have E1 say "City" and E2 have the total count without having to write a separate SUM formula.  Sorry that wasn't specified before.

Comment: Have a look at my answer posted. It combines the need for a city displayed with the above countif function.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this formula can help you out. It is not clear if you have a working column of cities associated with zip codes but if you do you could use something like this:

[image]

What this formula is doing is looking up the city in column B from the zip code list in column D, it is than tallying how many times that zip code appears in column A and setting it in parenthesis.

*Note that none of those cities are accurate to the zip codes used. Do not pay close attention to the city names in column B as they do not coordinate at all with the zipcode. I just wanted to show how to implement the city.

**FORMULA**

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP($D2:$D,$A$2:$B,2,FALSE)&" ("&COUNTIF(VALUE($A2:$A),VALUE($D$2:$D))&")"),"")
```

**UPDATE:**

Is this what you're looking for? It tallies up the total number of times a zip code from a corresponding column shows up, you can drag this formula over for as many cities as you want, if it is actually laid out in the way your image shows.

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D$2:D<>"",COUNTIF(VALUE($A2:$A),VALUE(D$2:D)),0)))
```

[image]

Comment: I updated the sample sheet again.  I'm slowly understanding how to ask the question so thank you for your patience with my question asking and giving me answers!

Comment: Please have a look at the updated section.

Comment: That's it!  Really appreciate your help!